# Data reset after leaving a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I have probably a very beginner question,yet I can't figure out why is it like that. I am trying to pass in constructor a StringBuilder which via Debugger I nailed but as soon as my last step in Debugger leaves this constructor which is in different class, it gets back to null. I know that it is a reference type and therefore only a reference gets copied but even if I pass it by reference by "ref" result is the same...maybe I get it wrong or there is something else wrong...

```
class DifferentClass
{
    public void Method()
    {
        StringBuilder[] PathtoFiles = new StringBuilder[numberOfImages];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
        {
            PathtoFiles[i] = new StringBuilder();
            // string pattern for correct file naming/saving
            string nameOfFile = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", adresaPath, i, ".jpg");
            PathtoFiles[i].Append(nameOfFile);
        }

        Pictures picture = new Pictures(ref PathtoFiles);
    }
}

class Pictures
{
    public StringBuilder[] sb;

    public Pictures(ref StringBuilder[] sb)
    {
        this.sb = sb;
    }

    public Pictures()
    {
    }

    public void LoadPictures(ImageList img)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.Count(); i++)
        {
            img.Images.Add(string.Format("pic{0}", i), Image.FromFile(sb[i].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Upon request I am enclosing another bit of code this time in class where the method LoadPictures gets called:

```
  class ThirdClass
  {   
    DifferentClass diff = new DifferentClass();
    Pictures picture = new Pictures();

    private void btn_Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diff.Method();
        //this is a control data is supposed to be saved in
        picture.LoadPictures(imageList1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What gets set back to null?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking about. What are your expectations? What is the issue? What does not work?

Comment: Your code works fine for me as is. What is the problem?

Comment: in class DifferentClass the StringBuilder gets filled up with data which I would like to use in class Pictures were this data sucessfuly gets copied to a global variable sb. With data located in sb I would like to work in method LoadPictures but as soon as the constructor gets closed the data in sb StringBuilder gets back to null and this is the problem I would like to sort out as I need to have the data stored in the Picture class.

Comment: Where are you calling LoadPictures? I wager you are creating another object somewhere it isn't initialized.

Comment: As I said, your classes work fine in my testing. I don't see you ever call `pictures.LoadPictures(imageList);` anywhere, though...

Comment: Calling of this method is done in a different/third class. This method is activated straight after Method in class Different class so there is no way this method would be called or called improperly.

Comment: @Gizzy can you show that class, how you call the method

Comment: @Gizzy Where do you define variable imageList1, where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there ya go:

```
class ThirdClass
  {   
    DifferentClass diff = new DifferentClass();
    Pictures picture = new Pictures();

    private void btn_Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diff.Method();
        //this is a control data is supposed to be saved in
        picture.LoadPictures(imageList1);
    }
  }
```

You are using the default constructor. Which doesn't set `StringBuilder[] Pictures.sb`

This is assuming of course that code you re-edited is the code you *are* working with.

In that case you need to figure out how to instantiate `DifferentClass`, maybe in `ThirdClass` ctor. And perhaps you want `DifferentClass.Method()` to return a `Picture` object you can initialize also in `ThirdClass` constructor.

There are several ways you can do this. Up to you to choose the best method.

Comment: Why would I have to use other than default constructor of the DifferentClass when the data inserted into ImageList in Pictures class  return that created ImageList in a method LoadPictures called in ThirdClass very the data gets the created ImageList control.

Comment: OK. You have a Picture(str[]) that's being used in DifferentClass. That object is different from the one used in ThirdClass. In other words you are creating 2 objects. Read over your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Method()
{
    // the StringBuilder
    // ...
    Pictures picture = new Pictures(ref PathtoFiles);
}
```

initialization of `picture` is correct. but it is a local variable, and when `Method()` is completed, you can't access it anymore

you can modify your method to keep result in variable on client-side:

```
public Pictures Method()
{
    // the StringBuilder
    // ...
    return new Pictures(ref PathtoFiles);
}
```

client-side

```
var pics = new DifferentClass().Method();
ImageList imgs = new ImageList();
pics.LoadPictures(imgs);
```